# Fastest way to write 0x00 to a zero-page memory location? (6502, Atari 2600)

Tags: memory, 6502, atari, atari-2600

I have a kernel in my 6502 game that writes two dots to a sprite, so for example:

```
........
........
.XX..XX.
.XX..XX.
........
........
```

Either 0, 1, or 2 dots can be on at a time. This is done one scanline at a time, so we're only looking at how to write the middle two lines.

So far I've implemented this by doing the following:

1. The accumulator is set to 0b01100000
2. X is set to 0b00000110
3. For the left dot, I use `STA $1B` (3 cycles) to only turn that dot on.
4. For the right dot, I use `STX $1B` (3 cycles) to turn that dot on.
5. For both dots, I can use the undocumented instruction SAX ($87) to write A | X to the value, so `SAX $1B` (3 cycles) to turn both on.

But if I need to turn both dots off, the quickest way I know of to write 0b00000000 to a register is to store $00 in Y and then write it. Of course, this means I can't use Y for other purposes in my code.

I don't need a trick that takes 3 cycles (4 or 5 are fine) but are there any possibilities, without consuming a register, to write 0x00 to a memory location in zero page on the 6502?

**EDIT:** The above description of the problem is incorrect (see comments). I actually set A=01100000, X=00000110, Y=01100110, and use SAX to write $00. The question as posed (writing 0x00 to a register without storing 0x00 in a register) is still answered in the replies.

Comment: It's late so I'm probably being an idiot but why is `SAX` not writing zero? The values you say are in `A` and `X` have no set bits in common.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 6502, but a common trick on x86 was to XOR a value with itself (x XOR x = 0, for any x; on x86, a register-to-register XOR encoded in two bytes instead of three for a 16-bit register store, so you'd save a byte by doing so). Might that work on the 6502?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling alas there are no register-to-register XORs (/EORs) on the 6502. Unrelated: the 65C02 added `STZ`, store zero, which would have been perfect here.

Comment: Also, I really think `SAX` writes the and, not the or. E.g. http://www.oxyron.de/html/opcodes02.html or, to quote http://nesdev.com/6502_cpu.txt : "Many undocumented commands do not use AND between registers, the CPU
just throws the bytes to a bus simultaneously and lets the
open-collector drivers perform the AND. I.e. the command called 'SAX',
which is in the STORE section (opcodes $A0...$BF), stores the result
of (A & X) by this way." (though that should be e.g. not i.e.)

Comment: Not directly addressing the question of a faster way to write 0, but is it maybe an option to reformulate and instead put the desired dot bit pattern %00, %01, %10, %11 in an index register, and do a lookup into a 4 value table translating it to %00000000, %00000110, % 01100000, %01100110 ?

Comment: @Tommy: The answer you deleted wasn't completely "wrong"--while the bus floating behavior is what I've most commonly observed, it depends upon the type of chips used in the cartridge and various other factors.  My 4A50 cartridge relies upon the bus coasting cycle-to-cycle, but included a bus keeper circuit to make that reliable.  I was perhaps a bit too definitive in saying the bus "coasts", since one shouldn't rely upon it without taking efforts to ensure it will work (as I did in my 4A50 cart).

Comment: @supercat my feeling was as simple as: the solution I offered wouldn't work, therefore it isn't an answer to the question. I suspect the lack of other answers strongly suggests that the answer is, yes, the author will probably need to keep `0` in `Y`?

Comment: @Tommy: If A and X have no bits in common, SAX will work just fine. If one wants to store values $00, $60, $06, and $066, one could keep $60 in A, $06 in X, and $66 in Y, and use SAX to write zero.

Comment: For the record, @Tommy is absolutely correct that SAX writes A & X. I misread my own code, which set A = 01100000, X = 00000110, Y = 01100110, and SAX writes 0. (So exactly what supercat deduced)

Digging into INC performing a 0x00 read, I know that [Stella hardcodes](https://github.com/stella-emu/stella/blob/3d879d00804daca747d56b92240ab9e551018999/src/emucore/tia/TIA.cxx#L410) its behavior to read from random noise or the last databus value. So it's possible the TIA behavior could be influenced indirectly, which is a great suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My second bite of the cherry: another of the [undocumented opcodes](http://nesdev.com/undocumented_opcodes.txt) is SYA/SHY/SAY which will:

> AND Y register with the high byte of the target address of the argument
>   + 1. Store the result in memory.

If you were willing and able to switch your usage of `X` and `A` then you could have `01100000` in X, therefore the argument you supply to `SAY` would be `001b - b01100000` = `ffbb`:

```
9C bb ff          ; SAY $ffbb,x
```

So that would store `Y & (ff+1)` to `ffbb + b01100000`, i.e. it would store `Y & 0 = 0` to `1b`, in five cycles. Your `Y` can hold anything, and isn't affected.

Comment: Thank you! Using SAY and XAS make this possible! `ldx #%01100110; ldy #00` then `.byte $9e, GRP0, #%000001110` for right dot, `.byte $9e, GRP0, #%111100000` for left dot, `stx GRP0` for both dots, and `sty GRP0` for neither. Accumulator is unaffected :)

Comment: Glad I could help eventually, even if only obliquely!